# Does SystemModeler have a spark gap among its analog electrical comonents?

Tags: system-modeler

I'm crafting a circuit to simulate, etc, and I can't find any spark gap component in its library.

How could it be custom designed, or imported, if it's missing from the library?

In the alternative, could a voltage sensor tied to a switch act as a substitute since the only purpose I'm using the spark gap for is to periodically dissipate a build up of voltage?

UPDATE

I'm having trouble using switches. I'm new at this. I'm getting an error message: *Error: Simulation model is not globally balanced, having 48 variables and 47 equations.*

[image: Error: Simulation model is not globally balanced, having 48 variables and 47 equations.]

Comment: As in the flip switches on/off to short circuit and drop voltage when the sensor reaches a specific value? Yes, it’d be a good method to reproduce the effect you’re looking for. As long as its ideal so a time constant isnt added...assuming thats an issue for your simulation.

Comment: Please also provide the Modelica code; you might also mention, that you cross-posted this on Wolfram Community.